# windows mobile releasing resources when application is closed (.net 3.5 cf)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-mobile, comparison

I have a basic .net 3.5 cf application with 4+ forms.  I am using a window handler class that I created to make sure that certain forms only have one instance open at a time where as other (Product Details for example) can be opened as many times as the user wants.  My problem lies in the fact that when the user closes all the forms (By clicking the "x" on the form rather than the "exit" button in the menu) that the application does not release the database connection.  In addition to this if the user closes all the forms and then opens the app up again their previous search results are shown rather than a new form.   How can I make sure to release all resources when the user closes all the forms??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (X) button is a minimize button, not a Close button.  You need to eitehr change the MinimizeButton on the Forms to false - which changes the (X) to an (ok) - or add logic to handle cases where all Forms get minimized.

Comment: this.MinimizeBox = false;
and all my problems are gone

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that on Windows Mobile that clicking the 'X' is more like minimizing a window than closing it.  It definitely won't exit the application, and may actually literally perform a minimize rather than a close on the form (I can't remember for sure)

So when they're "opening up the app again", it's likely it's just re-showing the same form.